# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize() method does not work in an AutoCAD plugin

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter, autocad-plugin

When I call the `Deserialize` method on an instance of `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` in `IExtensionApplication.Initialize` of an AutoCAD plugin, the next code line after that does not execute. What could be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you get any diagnostics? Exceptions? Stack traces? Not much to go on here...

Comment: Please be much more specific and provide any errors or exceptions thrown and **show your code**. We are no oracles. Also, please pay more attention to formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show some code, but in all likely hood the `Deserialize` call is throwing an exception and therefore the next line of code is not being executed. Use a try/catch block around the `Deserialize` to see if you can catch an exception and view/log the exception details that might point you to the root of the problem.